# Format java code adding 'this.' when missing

Tags: java, eclipse, format

I am refactoring a quite big project (~1800 source files) whose code need a huge cleaning.
Since we have Sonar constraints, we must follow a set of rules (about which we have no choice).

One of them is to add "this." to any reference to class object. And this one involves ... basicely all the files!

So, I am trying to find an automatic way to perform this.
I really cannot afford to do this one file at a time, and java format does not look like it can do such task.

So, whether I am wrong about java formater or there's a trick or plugin to do this the fast way, any tip is welcome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my opinion this is one of the cases where following the rules does not make sense at all.

Comment: Why don't you have a choice? Sonar metrics can be adjusted. And if your coding guideline was to omit it, then it's fine to follow the coding guideline and adapt the Sonar rule to your guideline. Consider someone else who must find out the amount of changed lines in order to determine the necessary re-tests. If you add the `this` everywhere, such an impact analysis will fail.

Comment: Usually, your QA team (I'm working in QA) does not need an immediate 100% pass on Sonar, but wants to see a trend. So, whenever you touch a file, fix it and enhance the metric. If a metric jumped from 0 to 100 within a very short time frame, I'd be really sceptical and I'd plan a complete system test instead of a re-test.

Comment: Actually, I am not a fan of stric application of the rules : especially formating and this very "this" rule... but those are given by our client as a go/no-go condition, and thus are of no-choice! Though, I agree with you: it's more a matter of contract than one of actual confidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'Source > Clean Up' menu. This will show you a menu where you can choose many different clean ups to be performed on the currently selected files.

The 'Member Accesses' tab has a couple of options to do with adding `this.`

You can also do similar actions when you save an edited file see the 'Java > Editor > Save Actions' preferences page.

Comment: Great! Thanks Greg : you have me save a few days of 'exciting' work!